# Question about speed

Tags: piano, technique

This piece from chopin, noctrune in c sharp minor, 4/4 time signature,
I have been playing this fast and I tried to divide the scale, and play slower until I get fast. When I opened the original song, I found that many people play this part double as fast as mine, I tried to play faster but there is no way to be that fast. How to improve my speed, I have been practicing this for 5 days, and my speed is fast, but it is not getting faster like the original one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Speed, clean and evenness can be compromised by either having improper movements or not having all of the proper ones. Only a knowledgeable teacher can discern what your issues are.  Perhaps it is time for a new teacher?

Keep in mind improper movement can be hardwired into your brain from day one and will haunt you forever by making your feel rusty some days, unable to warm up, making dumb mistakes while nervous or cold or, inconsistent with your mistakes.  Those are signs your brain is struggling with proper and improper movement.  Many of us overcome improper movement as we progress but the old tension habits are always there waiting to rear their ugly heads and cause us to stumble.

Find a teacher who can sleuth out what is holding you back.  Practice does not make perfect if your movement is not perfect.

Comment: for this particular passage, practice it in five groups of seven a......a.....a.....g#......g#...... with fingers 1.....1....1.....3....3.....